# How to install node-sass library in Angular application

Tags: angular, node-sass

In my angular 6 application we are using node-sass library 4.9.3.
I am trying to do ng build, it gives me an error,

Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.9.3

I tried a solution which says to download 'win32-x64-83_binding.node' and do npm install node-sass@4.9.3 --SASS_BINARY_PATH= ../win32-x64-83_binding.node

Still doesn't work and do ng build successfully.
How can we resolve node-sass library issue in Angular.

Comment: What's your node version?

Comment: 16.14.2 is the version

Comment: Then if you had followed the link given in the error message you can see that this node version is not supported. The maximum node version supported is 10 for your OS (Win 64bit). Either downgrade the node version (probably bad idea) or, as @oooogz suggested, use `sass` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I always delete "node-sass" from the package.json file and install 'sass' for the fix.

Comment: I tried deleting and installing didn;t work, I have node-sass defined in package.lock.json and not in package.json

Comment: Back up the package.lock.json file, after back up delete everything about node-sass, and try to install 'sass' again.